# Ошибка с github

Tags: git, github

Пытаюсь сделать проект на github 
После команды  `$git push -u origin master`
Выходит ошибка

```
c:\Games\bot>git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com//.git/':
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Врятли проблема  в браузере т.к использую Хром

Comment: `https://github.com//.git/` это точно показывается в логе или вы так замаскировали свой репозиторий?

Comment: думаю, лучше поменять http способ доступа к репозитарию на git/ssh. А ошибка говорит, что у Вас "человек в серединке" - или провайдер шалит, или кто то завелся

Answer (score -1):

Git сообщает, что в цепи серверов сертификации есть узел с само-подписанными сертификатом.

Вы можете отключить проверку сертификатов следующим образом:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: И это плохо, проверка сертификатов существует не просто так